# Freedesktop dbus error

Tags: systemd, d-bus, freedesktop

In .xsession-errors file I noticed strange message:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
```

**dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1**

What is the reason for this?